# Running shoes to avoid tendinitis

Tags: running, running-shoes, tendons

I like to run long distances (7-17 miles) on the trail, but occasionally or partially I also run on the road.

I have got pain similar to tendinitis in my left ankle, and I started looking for new shoes for my running with respect to this problem now. I learned that two qualities are important for shoes when you just had a tendinitis problem: high drop and moderate cushioning. However, the opinion split on wearing always the shoes with high drop and cushioning? Or, just temporary when the symptoms start?

One article claimed that if I always use cushioned shoes and with high drop some of the muscles are not activated. That would be counterproductive to avoid future problems.

I read these articles and more:

1. https://thewiredrunner.com/the-best-running-shoes-for-achilles-tendonitis/
2. https://www.steadyfoot.com/best-running-shoes-achilles-tendonitis/

What are the recommendations for professional runners when they suffer from tendinitis?

Is it a good idea to use different shoes? Or, is it ok always using high drop and cushioned shoes?

Comment: The problem likely isn't your shoes, but something else along the chain (hip / ankle mobility being a major cause). Not an answer because I'm far from an expert, but I can highly recommend the book Ready to Run by Kelly Starrett (I can't quote the section as the whole book covers how to rehab and protect against injuries, this being one of the ones listed)

Comment: I'm going to assert that "the recommendations for professional runners when they suffer from tendinitis" is "do what your professional coach tells you to do after he/she does research on your specific issue".  Also, even if there was a standard answer for pros, if you're not a pro it might well not work for you.  I recall reading something about how a pro, due to an injury ran 100 miles per week.  But that was down from their normal 150.